# Why is neutral required in three phase charging of electric vehicles?

Tags: battery-charging, three-phase, harmonics, neutral, balanced

Talking about both three-phase AC as well as DC fast charging (wherein 3 phase AC is converted to DC) in EVs, I think that the 3-phase rectifier represents a balanced 'load'. Why is then a neutral required? I ask this because I think that doing away with neutral would mean getting rid of the triple-n harmonics. Is my thinking correct?

Here is a type 2 connector pinout for reference:

[image: Type 2 connector]

Comment: Would it be used for single-phase charging?

Comment: You could absolutley design an EV charger for three phase delta with no neutral. But what you are looking at is a nearly universal plug which needs to adapt to several countries and several different scenarios, including three phase Y as well as single phase (with neutral).

Comment: @Transistor Yes, with single phase its L1+N and with three phases its L1+L2+L3+N

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that utilities won't have to bother about 3rd harmonic if threre was no neutral

Comment: @winny What about 3-phase star with no neutral? Would that work?

Comment: Star as in Y with no neutral? Almost unheard of but not impossible. But you are looking at a plug, and the plug needs to be somewhat universal.

Comment: @winny What about a DC fast charger taking 3-phase (no neutral) input and delivering DC to the car? Would the absence of neutral limit triple-n harmonics? Actually, the motivation to ask this is to figure out which of 3rd and 5th harmonic is going to be a major concern in case of 3-phase connection used for charging. In case of single phase, the 3rd should be dominant as with the case of SMPS.

Comment: Your asking a lot of questions and changing the subject slightly for each new. Three phase delta is like I said no issue to design for to deliver DC to the car. It's not impossible to limit the harmonics regardless of Y or delta, but you do have a point in odd harmonics for practical designs. Google PFC and three pase PFC.

Comment: I noticed something else - my 3 phase mobile EV charger when I charge with 3x16A (11kW) which is the max car charger can do and is loading the neutral wire with more current as it's getting a bit hot (I will measure soon the current in. the N wire with a clamp meter but if 4mm2 is hot is more than 25A, I guess around 32A). The phase wires are not hot. My socket is with PEN grounding which is common in my country when both negative and PE are tied together. Maybe it's normal if 3 separate 230V inverters are tied together in the onboard charger, but then I need a bigger wire for the neutral whic

Answer (score 4):

Who says a Neutral 'is required'?

What you've drawn is a standard 3 phase connector. The standard connector always includes a neutral, because then it can be used for single phase and unbalanced loads, as well as balanced 3 phase loads. The cost of an extra pin and extra wire for the neutral is far outweighed by the improvement in flexibility for use of the connector.

It's easy enough to design any specific rectified load, whether charger, motor, whatever, to use only 3 phase with no neutral. It's a waste of time to insist that it can only be plugged into sockets without a neutral, as this would severely limit where it could be used.

It's quite possible, and this may be my first cut at a fast charger, to run the power DC from a full bridge rectifier on the 3 phases, but the control electronics from a small transformer running from a single phase and neutral. It's possible to list all sorts of practical advantages to such a split.

Comment: In Ireland, which broadly follows the UK standards, we would use a 3P+E with no neutral connector if no neutral is available (as on a delta secondary, for example). This may be important as it prevents insertion of the 3P+N+E plugs which may be relying on N for correct operation.

Comment: Been bitten by the TP+N+E plug on an extension cable that turned out to be wired with 4 core cable (No neutral), quite the nasty surprise with an unbalanced lighting load.

Answer (score 1):

The easy, familiar, can build with jellybean switchmode parts approach to a charger is to build three single phase isolated converters and wire them star. This is because a 230V switchmode supply is a **very** standard thing and there are a LOT of off the shelf and high volume parts designed for such use.

Going delta increases the PFC output bus voltage (because you now have 400V RMS, so you need a PFC output north of 565V) which is out of reach for the common 400 or 450V caps and probably too high for the common mosfet choices (And you still need to build three of the things). Yea the primary current in each converter is a little lower, but the need for more expensive switching and bus caps probably trumps that consideration.

Now if you are going for a star connection, then you either need to ensure you have perfect balance and no triplen, or you need a neutral. You can of course use a synthetic neutral but that is quite a bit bit of iron, and you really don't need that weight on the vehicle, better to do that (if it is even required) on the shore side of the cable where its weight is not hurting range and acceleration.

Seriously, in the scheme of things a few amps or even a few tens of amps of triplen and imbalance is just not that big a deal, and is far easier to fix in the land side transformers then it is in a weight and size constrained mobile environment.